Правильна ли тут пунктуация? Надо ли разрывать "несмотря на то что"? Нужна ли запятая после И?
И несмотря на то, что я давно окончила школу, я её часто вижу во сне.

Возможны варианты:
(1) И несмотря на тО, что я давно окончила школу, я её часто вижу во сне. Три фразы.
(2) И несмотря на то что я дАвно окончила школу, я её часто вижу во сне. Две фразы.
Пояснение
Тема регулируется правилами Розенталя и не так проста.
Расчленение союза корректирует грамматику предложения, а также произношение. Мы включаем или не включаем местоименную часть  союза в главное предложение.  На решение оказывают влияние многие факторы, есть также особые условия расчленения. Также учитывается позиция  и распространенность придаточного.
В начале предложения союз чаще не расчленяется, а придаточное нераспространенное. Но надо учитывать контекст.
Удобно ориентироваться на произношение. Если ставить ударение  на местоименную часть, то союз расчленяется, а при другом ударении нет.
  2. В зависимости от смысла и интонации, логического 
  подчеркивания придаточной части сложноподчиненного 
  предложения, наличия в предложении определенных 
  лексических элементов и других условий сложный союз может 
  расчленяться на две части: первая входит в состав главной 
  части как соотносительное слово, а вторая выступает в роли 
  союза; в этих случаях запятая ставится только перед второй 
  частью сочетания (т. е. перед союзами что, чтобы, как) 
  [

Обратим внимание:
  5. Если придаточная часть сложноподчиненного предложениия 
  предшествует главной, сложный подчинительный союз чаще 
  всего не расчленяется: По мере того как бричка близилась к 
  крыльцу, глаза Манилова делались веселее (Г.); С тех пор 
  как я женился, я уж от тебя прежней любви не вижу (Остр.); 
  Прежде чем Самгин догадался помочь ей, она подняла с полу 
  книжку (М. Г.); Прежде чем ответить свахам, Степан 
  переглянулся с женой (Марк.); После того как повязку 
  сняли, боли до некоторой степени прошли (Фед.); Перед тем 
  как взяться за скрипку, он засучивал рукава рубахи, 
  обнажал грудь и становился у окна (Фед.); До того как она 
  стала работать почтальоном, она не задумывалась над 
  проблемой доставки почты в отдалённые места (Газ.)


Знаки в вопросе расставлены правильно. В более длинном предложении могут быть другие варианты.
